# SIM900 GRPS Shield Power down over issue AT+CIICR cmd(Bring Wireless Coms)

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm

I'm trying to get the TinySine SIM900 GPRS Shield working to get data over the GPRS network, using Arduino MEGA.

I'm Able to register my SIM with this Shield and even , but as soon as I sent the command AT+CIICR to Bring up the Wireless Coms, the Shiled powers down, all LEDs are OFF except the Red one.

What is the source of the Problem?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could start with showing the code of your sketch so we have a chance to see what might not be correct?

Answer (score 1):

The SIM9000 shield requires up to 2 Amperes to operate its wireless functions. Thus it must be powered from an external 9 Volt power supply, and the supply should be able to supply at least 2 Amperes, preferably more.

The shield will thus not work if powered through the Arduino, or using a low current external supply. The current draw for initial setup is low, hence registration of the SIM might be fine. Enabling wireless pushes the current draw beyond what your supply can cope with. This is shutting your setup down.

Replace (or use) a 2 Amperes or better 9 Volt DC power supply, feed this power to the shield, not the Arduino, and attempt your code again.

Note that there are some changes required in using an Arduino Mega instead of the Uno with the TinySine GPRS shield, which are described in the help files and on some example videos on YouTube.